# How to use IsNull() condition with date Columns in Pyspark dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

How can we use `isNull()` condition with date type columns in `Pyspark`. I need to update a column name **REGISTER_DATE** when it is null and satisfying other conditions also??

```
 data = [{"REGISTER_DATE": '', "FORM_DATE": '16-12-2022', "GENDER": Female, "Truth": True},
{"REGISTER_DATE": '13-09-2022', "FORM_DATE": '06-12-2022',"GENDER": Female"Truth":True},
{"REGISTER_DATE": '', "FORM_DATE": '20-12-2022', "GENDER": Female, "Truth": True},
{"REGISTER_DATE": '', "FORM_DATE": '18-12-2022', "GENDER": Female, "Truth": True}]


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
create_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

The `FORM_DATE` AND `REGISTER_DATE` Columns are of Date Datatype and gender is of STRING

The Query I am trying is:

```
create_df=create_df.withColumn('REGISTER_DATE',F.when((col('REGISTER_DATE').isNull()) & 
    (col('FORM_DATE') !='') & (col('GENDER')== 'FEMALE'), create_df.FORM_DATE)
    .otherwise(create_df['REGISTER_DATE']))
```

The query is running fine but it is not updating the column REGISTER_DATE even though the conditions are there in the source file.

According to my Knowledge, `isNull` use with *date* type column may be invalid. I want to update `REGISTER_DATE` Column nullvalue with `FORM_DATE` Column value if condition matched.

Comment: Please don't answer like change it into string type and then use isnull(), that i can't do as this column have multiple dependencies due to which i don't want to change the datatype of the Column

Comment: understood but you don't necessarily need to change the original column, you can just cast it inside the condition

Comment: per your example, `REGISTER_DATE` does not seem to have *nulls*. instead, it has *blanks*. you can check for that

Comment: Try my solution bigdata-lover it will convert them back to string if any contain any dependencies.

Comment: hi @MuhammadAli they are already in datetype

Comment: Yes, but if you replace missing string values with null you need to convert them to datetype. then use coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have this `data`:

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
|REGISTER_DATE|FORM_DATE |GENDER|TRUTH|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
|null         |2022-12-16|Female|True |
|2022-09-13   |2022-12-06|Female|True |
|null         |2022-12-20|Female|True |
|null         |2022-12-18|Female|True |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
```

with this schema:

```
root
 |-- REGISTER_DATE: date (nullable = true)
 |-- FORM_DATE: date (nullable = true)
 |-- GENDER: string (nullable = true) <-- doesn't matter
 |-- TRUTH: string (nullable = true)  <-- doesn't matter
```

If your type is `date` (on `REGISTER_DATE` and `FORM_DATE` columns), they will never have an empty string; `date` type is either a valid date or a `null`.

If we do this:

```
data = data.withColumn("REGISTER_DATE",
  when(col("REGISTER_DATE").isNull, col("FORM_DATE"))
    .otherwise(col("REGISTER_DATE")))
```

Then, we will have this as output:

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
|REGISTER_DATE|FORM_DATE |GENDER|TRUTH|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
|2022-12-16   |2022-12-16|Female|True |
|2022-09-13   |2022-12-06|Female|True |
|2022-12-20   |2022-12-20|Female|True |
|2022-12-18   |2022-12-18|Female|True |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+
```

In your example, you are filling the data with empty strings and claiming that they are of type `date`, but this can not be the case. Your `&` condition is making the whole statement turn to false, and that might be the case because you are trying to compare `date` type with empty string, which is never the case.

You just have to make sure that `REGISTER_DATE` and `FORM_DATE` are `date` and not `string`, and the casting (if you do it in the future) is correct.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

with the data you provided it is creating column of string data type. If that is the case then for empty string you have to use =='' condition. remember that an empty string is not same as null. However if you mean to say that your actual data has column of date data type and this example code/data having string is incorrect then we can not insert empty strings in a column of date data type in spark.

Your code is correct and it will work without any modification if

1. your data is proper date datatype, not date stored in string data type. and
2. value is proper null not empty string.

[screenshot showing datatype of the dataframe created from data provided in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ64s.png)

[screenshot showing it works with stringDatatType=='' & DateType can not accept object '' in type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbism.png)

Comment: Thanks for contributing by answering! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works for your solution, convert REGISTER_DATE and FORM_DATE to datetype and then implement your logic or convert into date and then use coalesce function just like in sql. I convert REGISTER_DATE and FORM_DATE back to string because if it contain any dependencies.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()
from pyspark.sql import *
from  pyspark.sql.functions import *
data = [{"REGISTER_DATE": '', "FORM_DATE": '16-12-2022', "GENDER": 'Female', "Truth": True},
{"REGISTER_DATE": '13-09-2022', "FORM_DATE": '06-12-2022',"GENDER": 'Female', "Truth":True},
{"REGISTER_DATE": '', "FORM_DATE": '20-12-2022', "GENDER": 'Female', "Truth": True},
{"REGISTER_DATE": '', "FORM_DATE": '18-12-2022', "GENDER": 'Female', "Truth": True}]# Define Schema without infering spark
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
create_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
print('Before converting to date and handling null')
create_df.printSchema()
create_df.show()
create_df = create_df.withColumn('FORM_DATE', to_date(col('FORM_DATE'), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
create_df = create_df.withColumn('REGISTER_DATE', to_date(col('REGISTER_DATE'), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
# Solution 1:
# create_df = create_df.withColumn('REGISTER_DATE',when((col('REGISTER_DATE').isNull()) & 
#     (col('FORM_DATE').isNotNull()) & (col('GENDER')== 'Female'), create_df.FORM_DATE)
#     .otherwise(create_df['REGISTER_DATE']))
# Solution 2:
create_df = create_df.withColumn('REGISTER_DATE', coalesce('REGISTER_DATE', 'FORM_DATE'))
# convert back to string 
create_df = create_df.withColumn('FORM_DATE', col('FORM_DATE').cast('string'))
create_df = create_df.withColumn('REGISTER_DATE', col('REGISTER_DATE').cast('string'))
print('After converting to date and handling null')
create_df.printSchema()
create_df.show()
```